# Как сделать произвольный placeholder?

Tags: html, css

Как можно правильно реализовать такой placeholder?
Или же это обычный блок с absolute который пропадает при клике?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а в инспекторе посмотреть не пробовали?) там весь код есть) ctrl+shift+c и вперед.

Comment: Это скрин из фотошопа.

Comment: тогда ладно. да, это делается блоками с position:absolute. placeholder не получится так кастомизировать, хотя менять ему цвет и даже добавить бордер вполне можно. но вот разделить на две по-разному стилизованные части - нет.